# A simple .click() and .html() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

UPDATE: Here is a jsfiddle that better exhibits my problem. Several attempted solutions are at the bottom of the post.

http://jsfiddle.net/2ZLse/7/

Now I know I should know how to do this, but this simple .click() then .html() event is not working. It's part of something slightly more complicated, but I don't see how any of that could be preventing this from working.

The functionality is a control panel that takes over the image displaying div when it needs more room to display input forms. I hope that makes sense. I've tried putting the event other places in the code, changing classes to IDs, and lots of little things I was pretty sure wouldn't fix the problem. It might be something simple, I hope it is. Here is what is hopefully the relevant code.

HTML

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<!-- load up bootstrap -->
</head>
<?php
//prompt for username before creating page
include 'login.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION['name'])){
loginForm();
}
else {
//begin page content
//don't know if the fact this is all inside of php brackets is relevant. Might be.
?>

<!-- lots of stuff I don't think is relevant. -->

                            <!-- controls and input display-->
                            <!-- controls and input display-->
<div id="inputbox">
<form>
<button type="button" id="talkcontrol" class="btn btn-default">Talk</button>
<button type="button" id="shoutcontrol" class="btn btn-default">Shout</button>
<button type="button" id="watchcontrol" class="btn btn-default">Watch</button>
<button type="button" id="showcontrol" class="btn btn-default">Show</button>
<button type="button" id="sharecontrol" class="btn btn-default">Share</button>
<button type="button" id="leavecontrol" class="btn btn-default">Leave</button>
</form>
<br>
</div>

                                <!-- images and continued input extension-->
        <!-- imagebox also acts as control panel -->
<div id="imagebox">
<img width="8%" src="banners/previous.gif">
<img src="images/smokingman.jpg" width="80%" height="80%" class="img-rounded">
<img width="8%" src="banners/next.gif">
</div>
```

And here is the javascript and jquery, which I suspect is where the problem lay.

```
var imagebox = '<img width="8%" src="banners/previous.gif">' + 
'<img src="images/smokingman.jpg" width="80%" height="80%" class="img-rounded">' +
'<img width="8%" src="banners/next.gif">';

var watchform =  '<img src="/venue/banners/videoid.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image"><br>' + 
'<form action="post/watchpost.php" method="post">' + 
'<input type="text" name="watchid" /><br>' + 
'<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Contribute" />' + 
'</form>' + 
'<br><br><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" class="nevermind">nevermind</button>';

$(document).ready(function(){
                                    //control functionality
$('.nevermind').click(function(){
    $('#imagebox').html(imagebox);
});

$('#watchcontrol').click(function(){
    $('#imagebox').html(watchform);
});
});
```

UPDATE: I did as HoangHieu suggested below, this did not work.

```
$('.nevermind').innerHTML();
$('.nevermind').on("click",function(){
    $('#imagebox').html(imagebox);
});
```

Also, the duplicate I was marked as is not helping, but I'll keep reading it and try to apply it to my code.

UPDATE: I kept reading, and I just don't see it. It seems to be a question about .hover and a loop. Is there something I'm missing?

UPDATE: I tried as Antti Haapala suggested below, and it did not work either.

```
$(document).on('click', '.nevermind', function() {
    $('#imagebox').html(imagebox);
});
```

Both Antti and Hoang's suggestions break my javascript, and yet jslint says the code is valid. I'll keep using trial and error.

Comment: **$("#id").innerHTML();

$("#id").on("click",function(){
       
});**

Comment: I tried that, and it broke the click functions that were working.

Comment: The element used in `$('.class')` must exist in the dom when you execute that piece of code. Try `$(document).on('click', '.nevermind', function() {});`

Comment: Demo here :) ... http://jsfiddle.net/2ZLse/3/

Comment: with class here: http://jsfiddle.net/2ZLse/5/

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, it does not work, unfortunately. Breaks my javascript. I edited my question to reflect my attempt.

Comment: @HoangHieu, your jsfiddle does not involve a button being rendered, and then that button being used to return the div state to it's original form. That may be a meaningful difference between you're code and mine. I'll keep playing with it.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle that better explains my problem. http://jsfiddle.net/2ZLse/6/

Comment: **You have a bug in your HTML. `class="btn btn-default" class="nevermind"` means that nothing has class `nevermind`**. Fix that and then this is a duplicate of the other bug, and [my code works](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZLse/8/).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala for whatever reason, I can not get it to work on my project, even though I can rewrite the functionality in jsfiddle, have it work in jsfiddle, and move it to my project. What could be the problem? There is ajax elsewhere on the page. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Get a debugger for your browser, say [Firebug for Firefox](https://getfirebug.com/).